# Fail to display hash string in textbox using c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have problem to display the MD5 hash result in textbox. The code works fine using command line. The code is as shown below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = GetMD5HashFromFile();
    }

private static string GetMD5HashFromFile()
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Desktop\test.txt", FileMode.Open);
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
        file.Close();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I would like to calculate hash and display the hash string directly in textbox. Am I got the programming concept wrong or there is some missing step? Thanks!

Comment: What is your exact problem then?

Comment: You are modifying the textbox inside the textbox Changed event? That could cause a nasty loop.

Comment: @Djerry There is no display of the md5 hash result in textbox when I run the application. Is there something wrong with the code or how can I make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextChanged` event handler is called when the user has entered text in the TextBox (or when the `Text` property has changed for any other reason). It is the wrong place to assign the hash string to the `Text` property.

You may put it somewhere else, perhaps in a button click handler:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1"/>
    <Button Content="Set Text" Click="ButtonClick"/>
</StackPanel>

private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = GetMD5HashFromFile();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens. It works this way but is it possible to show the result without having to click the button?

Comment: Of course. The Button was just an example. You may assign the `Text` property more or less wherever you like, *except* in a TextChanged handler of the same TextBox. In order to show the hash string right after the application has started, you may place the assignment in your MainWindow's constructor, right after `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: And just in case you only want to display the string, but don't want to have it editable, you should use a `TextBlock` instead of a `TextBox`.